# Automatically reclaim PersistentStorage (NFS mount) after PersistentStorageClaim is deleted?

Tags: openshift, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims, tekton, tekton-pipelines

Situation: Using Tekton tasks to build and deploy following this [tutorial](https://github.com/openshift/pipelines-tutorial). After running the pipeline, it creates a pod that requires persistent volume. A persistent volume claim is automatically created to try and bind to a PV.

However, what if I want to run the pipeline again and again? I noticed after a pipeline run (right now it's failing for unrelated reasons), the PVC will no longer be needed, but the PV will be in a **Released** state. I can manually edit out the PVC in the YAML.

I looked into [dynamic provisioning](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.2/storage/dynamic-provisioning.html) but the plug ins there do not seem to be for NFS, but rather other tools with APIs.

Is there an option for me to not have to manually reclaim my PV every time?

Comment: AFAIK, this is a side effect of openshift/pipelines.  I've never seen Tekton leave behind any PVC after running a pipeline and tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PersistentVolumes can be configured to automatically clean themselves up when released. You can configure this in your persistent volume definition at `persistentvolume.spec.persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy`.

Take a look at [Reclaim Volumes](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.3/storage/understanding-persistent-storage.html#reclaiming_understanding-persistent-storage) in the official OpenShift documentation.

> **Retain** reclaim policy allows manual reclamation of the resource for those volume plug-ins that support it.
>
> **Recycle** reclaim policy recycles the volume back into the pool of unbound persistent volumes once it is released from its claim.
>
> **Delete** reclaim policy deletes both the PersistentVolume object from OpenShift Container Platform and the associated storage asset in external infrastructure, such as AWS EBS or VMware vSphere.

In your case you want to use `Recyle`